# Quick way to copy the rest of a line?

Tags: emacs, key-mapping

In Emacs, I want to copy the rest of the current line.

The regular way is to select the rest of the current line, and then `M-w`.

A quicker way is `C-k C-_`.

Is there a non-customized way using only one combination-key or quicker?

Comment: `C-k C-y` is a shift key simpler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`C-k C-_` kills and undoes the kill. `C-k C-y` kills and yank back. Strictly speaking, neither copies.

If you want to really copy, use:

- `C-SPC C-n M-w` to copy with newline.
- `C-SPC C-e M-w` to copy without newline.

Another way, you can use [Viper-mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ViperMode) to emulate vi key bindings.

Comment: C-k C-y will still need C-x C-s to save, so that is four!